# ListView in android behaves very jerky in android using custom Adapter

Tags: android

I am using Custom Adapter for showing ListView,But my ListView behaves very jerky

code for my Custom adapter

```
   class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<T> arr ;

    public ListAdapter(Context con,ArrayList<T> arrayList) {
    arr = arrayList;
    context = con;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return arr.size();
    }
    @Override
            public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                return arg0;
            }
    @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                return arg0;
            }

@Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView == null ){
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = View.inflate( context,R.layout.match_introspection_list_item, null);
                viewHolder.teamFlagOneImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                viewHolder.teamFlagTwoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                viewHolder.teamOneTextView =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.teamTwoTextView =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                viewHolder.dateTextView =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                viewHolder.placeTextView =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                viewHolder.descTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final MatchIntrospectionObjects obj = arr.get(pos);
            viewHolder.teamOneTextView.setText(obj.home_team_abbrev);
            viewHolder.teamTwoTextView.setText(obj.away_team_abbrev);
            viewHolder.descTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Description: </b>")+obj.matchdescription);
            if(obj.date.equals("")){}else
                viewHolder.dateTextView.setText(splitDate(obj.date));

            viewHolder.placeTextView.setText(obj.venue);

            imageLoader.displayImage(FLAG_BASE_URL+obj.home_flag, viewHolder.teamFlagOneImageView, options, animateFirstListener);
            imageLoader.displayImage(FLAG_BASE_URL+obj.away_flag, viewHolder.teamFlagTwoImageView, options, animateFirstListener);

            return convertView;
        }
}
```

This is mycode for ListAdpater

and I am setting ListAdapter Like this in Oncreate() method

```
ListAdapter adapter =new ListAdapter(this,listArray);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This code help me to minimize some extent jerky effect in my ListView.

I am fetching Images from URL using Universal Image Loader If same image want to fetch for different cell from same URL then Universal ImageLoader fetch again and agian or it fetched once in lifetime and then get from cache Image available ?

Comment: use [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for loading images for sever to ListView

Comment: You are not caching any data or using ListView's recycle feature, utilizing both of those will help immensely. Please watch the Google I/O talk [Turbo-Charge your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) and / or [World of ListView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html).

Comment: thanks @ρяσѕρєяK Android-Image-Loader is very useful.

Comment: thanks @Sam for video link share

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK please provide any solution regarding my second question about UniversalImageLoader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
ViewHolder viewHolder;
if (convertView == null) {
viewHolder = new ViewHolder;
convertView = rowInflater.inflate(context,R.layout.team_ranking_list_item, null);
viewHolder.currentRatingText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Rating);
viewHolder.countryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TeamNameTextView);
viewHolder.rating = (GradientTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RatingTextView);
viewHolder.rank =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RankTextView);
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else 
 {
viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
//set data here

return convertView;
}


 static class ViewHolder {
 TextView currentRatingText;
 TextView countryName;
 GradientTextView rating;
 TextView rank;
}
```

Use a view holder for smooth scrolling and performance. If you are displaying 100 images instead of findviewById every time do it when your view is null and you set set the data. Recycling vies.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

You can also use lazy list. https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

For displaying large number of images you can use Universal Image Loader. (gives you lot more configuration options than lazylist)

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. It is based on Lazy List.You can display images from sdcard, phone memory or from server. You can display a error image if downlaod failed. Can display images with rounded corners. Can cache on disc or memory. Can compress image.

In your custom adapter constructor

```
   File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "your folder");

  // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
  imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
  // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
  ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
      // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
     .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
     .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
     .enableLogging()
     .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
 options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
 .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image
 .cacheInMemory()
 .cacheOnDisc()
 .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
 .build();
```

In your getview()

```
   ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
   imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);//provide imageurl, imageview and options
```

Comment: I have implemented as per your code above still my ListView behaves jerky

Comment: No you have implemented a viewholder at all http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html. Pls go through every part of the answer not just the codes.

Comment: @andrewww you have not implemented ViewHolder. Pls implement ViewHolder and if the problem still exists get back and inform. Edit the question and post what you have done so far.

Comment: I have edited My question please find edited in getView() method , my Litview still finds jerky..

Comment: why is that you have two  imageLoader.displayImage();? Try by commmenting one of them.

Comment: I have two Images in a ListItem ,please check both have different url and Imageviews..

Comment: i do not know about displaying two images using universal imageloader. Try commenting one just for testing. See if your listview is still jerky.

Comment: your code help me to minimize jerky effect for some extent but still LitsView is not extreme smooth...and thanks I have accepted your answer.

Comment: did you use both images?. Thanks for accepting. But i am curious about this case. I haven't tried this. Check more options https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. May be you can still minimize the jerky effect. If you have issues post it in the link. The author will provide you a solution

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the video that @Sam recommended is that you are inflating your views every time you scroll rather than using the `recycler` built into `ListView`. You're trying to speed things up by using an `Array` of `RelativeLayout`s, but a much better way to do this is to create a `ViewHolder` for your view so that it can be reused. The `ViewHolder` is a static inner class. Define it like so:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView currentRatingText;
    public TextView countryName;
    public GradientTextView rating;
    public TextView rank;
    ...
```

}

Then define your inflater in the constructor of your custom adapter like so: `rowInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Then, your `getView()` method should look something like this.

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder;
if (convertView == null) {
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder;
    convertView = rowInflater.inflate(context,R.layout.team_ranking_list_item, null);
    viewHolder.currentRatingText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Rating);
    viewHolder.countryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TeamNameTextView);
    viewHolder.rating = (GradientTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RatingTextView);
    viewHolder.rank =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RankTextView);
    ...
    //Views can hold a tag, which is an object. By setting the viewHolder as the
    //view tag, we can grab it next time so we don't need to re-inflate everything.
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
//Here is where you set all of you views' data.
T t = arr.get(pos);
viewHolder.currentRatingText.setText(t.getText());
viewHolder.countryName.setText("UAE");
...
return convertView;
```

}

`ConvertView` is the view that left the screen and can now be reused for the new view on the bottom of the screen. As suggested above, caching images would definitely help, but I think this is enough to get the list scrolling smoothly.

The video is still mandatory viewing; Romain Guy is the boss.

Comment: Thanks for ans , Video is very useful i have gone through it ,see my edited question , My list view still behaves jerky